# FIrebase Rule: How use $ to access an ancestor node's data?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Goal: Only the authenticated "owner" user can read/write their documents in "some-collection."

Example Query: /users/peter/some-collection/myDoc

The user node has a string uid field as is common with many of the Firebase rules examples.

I've read all the documentation and it says you can put a {variable} in the path and use the $ to reference it, but I can't get this rule to "compile" using the online database rules editor:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{user}/some-collection/{doc} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == $(user).data.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying allow access to a sub-collection of the user by validating the uid at the user/account-level.

It doesn't like the dollar sign:

> Error saving rules - Line 26: Unexpected '$'.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do.  For questions about security rules, it's always helpful to show an actual query that should be allowed by the rule, stating exactly what documents should be matched, and what they contain.

Answer (score 0):

The `$(user)` that you get from the wildcard in your path is a string value, not a document.

If you want to access data from the `/users/{user}` document, you can [do a `get()` call for that data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents):

```
allow read, write: 
      if request.auth.uid == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(user)).data.uid;
```